# Python, virtualenv, exofrills text editor

Tags: python, virtualenv

[exofrills](https://github.com/scopatz/xo) text editor requires python 3 and I'm using python 2 as default, so I installed exofrills using virtualenv successfully in user/env/exofrills directory, wherein python 3 is the default

what I want to know is how to launch the editor now??

I think you should've inferred that I'm a newbie :), so could you provide some learning resource (for those stuff) with the answer

Comment: I'd like to know this too!

Comment: What happens when you simply run `xo [-h] path` in the virtualenv?